# extra padding getting added up while pdf print javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

While printing pdf with window.print

[image: The table looks like this]

but while print on pdf there is an extra padding at td level bewtween a and b points any solution for the same?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 You can write styles based on these CSS rules

 @media screen {
    // css code for the screen only
 }
 @media print {
   // css code for the print window
 }
 @media screen, print {
  //css code for screen and print window
 }
```

Comment: Thankyou @nj_96 i have tried this works . one more point was that i was using typography tag from material Ui so it was adding extra space while printing this now have removed it worked fine

Comment: I'm happy to help @BhartSupriya. Happy Coding :D